# what are な and ね in ごめんね and ごめんな

Tags: expressions

i often heard 'ね' or 'な' at the end of word like かわいいな, かわいいね, いいな or いいね.

i also often hear word that ended with よ but i can't recall the example for now.

so my questions are:

1. what are they (な、ね) called?
2. how to apply them to another word? i mean are they just for noun or adjective? i think not every noun can be attached with them, correct?
3. whats the meaning of them?

any link related article about them are very welcome. ありがとうございます。

Comment: `how to apply them to another word? i mean are they just for noun` But.. you'd say きれいな花ね。 but not きれいな花な。 You'd instead say
きれいな花だな (きれいな花だね is also good), no?

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ     Judging by them saying they " also often hear words ending with "yo"" I think they are specifically interested in な as a sentence ending particle, but good point.

Comment: i am confused now, so きれいな花な is wrong?

Comment: @Kakashi sort of, we are discussing how the な used after きれい is because there are such things as な adjectives. You would say きれいな花だな。@ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ I actually don't know why though, could you explain?

Comment: @Gabby  な as a sentence-ending particle (終助詞) can attach to the terminal form (終止形), e.g. (i-adjective)かわいい+な (na-adjective)しずかだ+な (verb) 困る+な, ～よな, ～だよな etc. 　ね can also attach to the terminal form, e.g. かわいい+ね, しずかだ+ね, 困る+ね, ～よね, ～だよね, ～わね etc. and can also be used as a copula, e.g. (noun)子ども+ね, (na-adjective)しずか+ね.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what are they (な、ね) called?

They are called sentence-ending particles. **However, な can also come along with what are called な adjective.**

> how to apply them to another word? i mean are they just for noun or adjective? i think not every noun can be attached with them, correct?

Typically they will add on to the end of the sentence, except for な which can also be used with certain adjectives.

Here are some examples.

**For な、you can:**

1. Indicate emotion. Mostly used by men.

(な, in this usage, is often lengthened to なあ）

> あの人はすばらしいな。That person is really great [something]!

2. Ask for another person's agreement. Used by men.

> あの車は新車だよな。That's a new car, right?/That's a new car, I bet.

3. Soften the effect of an assertion.

> この映画は良くなかったな。This movie just wasn't very good.

4. Soften a command or request (first example, a women speaking with typical くださいな　pattern; second example, a man.)

> 成田まで行ってくださいな。Narita [Airport], please [if you please].
>
> 明日必ず来いな。Be sure to come tomorrow.

5. Indicate a prohibition. Used by men.

> 絶対にあいつに会うな。Stay away from that bum, you hear./Keep clear of that guy.

**For ね、you can:**

Note: ね is sometimes pronounced ねえ。

1. Indicates emotion or feelings of admiration.

> きれいな花ねえ。What a pretty flower!

2. Indicates agreement with the other person.

> 本当にそうですね。Yes, that's quite true./That's so true.

3. Softens a request.

> 必ず手紙を下さいね。Be sure to write [me a letter].

4. Indicates a request for confirmation.

> あの本、持って来て下さったでしょうね。You brought me that book, didn't you [as I asked you to]?/ I suppose you brought that book for me.

5. Indicates a mild assertion of, or variance in, opinion.

> そうですかね。Oh, is that so?/ I wonder. /You think so?

6. Indicates a mild assertion.

> 私は北海道の方が寒いと思うんですけどね。I would think that Hokkaido is cooler.

**For よ, you can:**

1. Urge a course of action.

> もうだいぶ歩いたから、この辺でちょっと休もうよ。
>
> Let's take a break about here, guys.
>
> We've already walked quite a bit.

2. Indicate a request (Although other particles can do this too)

> 私の家にも来てくださいよ。Come to *my* house, too.

3. Indicates a statement of certainty.

> 今日は金曜日ですよ。Today is Friday, you know. (Stated, for example, after someone has claimed otherwise.)

4. Indicates scolding or contempt.

> あの人は仕事ができないわよ。He just can't do the work!